# Can't open filepath in Python if filepath contains "," or "="

Tags: python, path, subprocess, popen

I can't open paths and highlight files if the path contains either "," or "=" (and maybe other symbols).

This code works if the path doesn't have the characters mentioned above:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,' + str(Path(link)))
```

I don't get any error it just defaults to open "This PC".

Does anyone out there know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple arguments with [`check_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) instead. Python will escape them correctly:

```
from subprocess import check_call
check_call(['explorer', '/select,', str(Path(link))])
```

Comment: @Fred_Alb It should be fixed now.

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know about check_call. It works! Thank you. I get an error saying

"subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['explorer', '/select,P:\\...filepath...']' returned non-zero exit status 1."    but it still works.